# How do you import the node module "child_process" into an angular project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, shell, electron

I am trying to run a shell script in my angular application. I found that I might be able to use the node library "child process" to do this. However, either way I try to import the library I get the error:
'error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Users...'

I've tried both:
const cp = require('child_process');
import {cp} from 'child_process';

but neither seem to work.

Any help importing this [module](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_asynchronous_process_creation) would be greatly appreciated

Also, it seems there's not a whole lot about running shell scripts in Angular, which makes me think this probably isn't the norm? Am I crazy for this? :)

Comment: Do you use Angular in Electron?

Comment: So I am creating a desktop application (using Electron) to parse, analyze, and display log files. The two use cases I have for using OS processes is 1. to untar tarballs with logs in them. And 2. is kinda just experimenting, might ask a separate question about it. 3. (A bonus) I'm just curious if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing like this,

**const { exec } = require('child_process')**